# How to resolve TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len() in Python Selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to print all similar elements but keep getting an error (I am using **Pycharm**).

**Error:**

```
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

This line is the one throwing the error: `num_page_items = len(productname)`

**Full selenium code:**

```html
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/driver/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.blibli.com/jual/batik-pria?s=batik+pria")
productname = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-title']")
oldprice = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.old-price-text").text
discount = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.discount > span").text
saleprice = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.new-price-text").text

num_page_items = len(productname)
for i in range(num_page_items):
   print(productname[i].text + " : " + oldprice[i].text + " : " + discount[i].text + " : " + saleprice[i].text)


driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
num_page_items = len(productname) 
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

**productname** is assigned the return type from `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-title']")`, which is a *WebElement* and  *WebElement* have no method as `len()`. `len()` can be invoked on a `List`.

### Solution

As you are trying to access `List` items as in :

```
print(productname[i].text + " : " + oldprice[i].text + " : " + discount[i].text + " : " + saleprice[i].text)
```

So **productname**, **oldprice**, **discount** and **saleprice** needs to be of `List` type.

But your code reads as :

```
productname = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-title']")
oldprice = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.old-price-text").text
discount = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.discount > span").text
saleprice = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.new-price-text").text
```

Where **productname** is a *WebElement* and **oldprice**, **discount**, and **saleprice** are *text*. So you need to change them as a `List` of *WebElements* as follows :

```
productname = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-title']")
oldprice = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.old-price-text")
discount = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.discount > span")
saleprice = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.new-price-text")
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `find_element_by_xpath` which find and returns the first `WebElement` matching the selector. You need to use `find_elements_by_xpath` which returns all the matching elements